# Some problems with PADDING in bg color of ONLY the inline text element

Tags: html, css, background

Thank you for your time. I am trying to add background color to the TEXT only and I have managed to do so with

```
.post-title {
text-transform:capitalize; 
margin-top:4px; 
margin-bottom:1px; 
font-size:22px; 
background-color:#FFF; 
display:inline;
}

<div class="col-sm-4 featured">
     <center><img src="image/alutila.jpg"></center>
     <div class="featured-text">
        <div class="meta">Environmental Science, Social Science</div>
        <h2 class="post-title"><a href="#">This is the first time I am doing this</a></h2>
     </div><!--featured text-->
</div>
```

Screenshot: http://screencast.com/t/EwI0voEG

But as you can see there is no padding on the left or right side of the text. When I add **padding:5px 10px;** to the **.post-title** class it only adds the padding to the first and last word of the sentence. Also, some text gets blocked by the background.

Screenshot:http://screencast.com/t/DSsVKlQu

What is the proper way to achieve the background with proper padding so that it looks good.

Answer (score 0):

You must give a padding to the .featured-text... to .post-title you can set only the margin. h2 behaviour is default as block... If you want inline h2, you must set display:inline to .post-title, not on .featured-text

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this 


.post-title {
text-transform:capitalize; 
margin-top:4px; 
margin-bottom:1px; 
font-size:22px; 
background-color:#FFF; 
display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but this creates a background for the whole div. I dont want bg for the whole div, just for the text with a little padding.

Comment: Can you pls do jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

Apply `line-height` for that.

```
   .post-title 
   {
    text-transform:capitalize; 
     margin-top:4px; 
     margin-bottom:1px; 
     font-size:22px; 
     line-height:32px;
     background-color:#FFF; 
     display:inline;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! And what should I do about the left and right padding?